# input check functions in python classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I want to create a check on inputs of a particular class, I have the following made up example:

```
class NmbPair:
    def __init__(self, a = None, b = None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.a == other.a and self.b == other.b:
            return True
        return False

class NmbOperation:
    def __init__(self, *, NmbPair1, NmbPair2):
        if not self.check(NmbPair1, NmbPair2): ## this is the check
            return
        self.NmbPair1 = NmbPair1
        self.NmbPair2 = NmbPair2
        self._add_first_nmb()

    def check(self, a, b):
        if a == b:
            return False

    def _add_first_nmb(self):
        self.sum_a = self.NmbPair1.a + self.NmbPair2.a
```

so i want to check that the input NmbPairs are not the same, and if they are I do not want an instance of NmbOperation to be created.

For example:

```
t1 = NmbPair(2, 3)
t2 = NmbPair(2, 2)
Op1 = NmbOperation(NmbPair1 = t1, NmbPair2 = t2)
print(Op1.sum_a)
```

But this throws the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NmbOperation' object has no attribute 'sum_a'
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `NmbOperation` object for which the `__init__` method immediately returns before executing the lines

```
self.NmbPair1 = NmbPair1
self.NmbPair2 = NmbPair2
self._add_first_nmb()
```

This is because `self.check(NmbPair1, NmbPair2)` returns `None`, so `not self.check(NmbPair1, NmbPair2)` is `True`.

Therefore, the attribute `sum_a` is never set since `_add_first_nmb` is never called.

Your `check` method is equivalent to:

```
def check(self, a, b):
    if a == b:
        return False
    else:
        return None
```

You probably want

```
def check(self, a, b):
    return not a == b
```